# Setting X-Axis Scale in Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a program to set the range of values visible in an excel chart based on user input.  The program works when there are dates in the x-axis.  It throws an error when I try to modify the code for an x-axis that has a number rather than a date.

This is the code that works (x-axis of chart is an excel formatted date):

```
Sub xaxis_reset()
  Dim start_date As Variant
  Dim end_date As Variant
  Dim w As Long, ws As Long
  Dim z As Long, obj As Long

  start_date = InputBox("Start Date")
  end_date = InputBox("End Date")
  ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2

  For w = 1 To ws
    obj = Worksheets(w).ChartObjects.Count
    For z = 1 To obj
      Worksheets(w).ChartObjects(z).Activate
      With ActiveChart
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = DateValue(start_date)
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = DateValue(end_date)
      End With
    Next z
  Next w
End Sub
```

This is my attempt to modify the code to work for a chart that has numbers (year-months) in the x-axis.

```
Sub xaxis_reset()
  Dim start_yr_mnth_cd As Variant
  Dim end_yr_mnth_cd As Variant
  Dim w As Long, ws As Long
  Dim z As Long, obj As Long

  start_yr_mnth_cd = InputBox("Start YR_MNTH_CD")
  end_yr_mnth_cd = InputBox("End YR_MNTH_CD")
  ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2

  For w = 1 To ws
    obj = Worksheets(w).ChartObjects.Count
    For z = 1 To obj
      Worksheets(w).ChartObjects(z).Activate
      With ActiveChart
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = start_yr_mnth_cd
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = end_yr_mnth_cd
      End With
    Next z
  Next w
End Sub
```

The line `.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = start_yr_mnth_cd` throws an error.

I've tried changing `start_yr_mnth_cd` and `end_yr_mnth_cd` from `Variant` to `Long`.  I've also tried changing the x-axis values in the chart to the general format instead of number.  I've made similar changes to the source data in the excel file, even though I don't think that should make a difference.  I'm not sure where else to look at this point.

Just in case it helps, this is what the x-axis source data looks like:

```
201701
201702
201703
201704
201705
201706
201707
201708
201709
201710
201711
201712
201801
201802
201803
201804
201805
201806
201807
```

Comment: Does Excel see those numbers for the x-axis source data as dates, as numbers or as text?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have them as numbers.  I just tried setting them as text and I got an error in the same place.  If I set it as a date excel interprets the data incorrectly.

Comment: @Jarom what do you mean by number (Year-Months)?  Can you write an example of the format of the number. Is it 2018-2 or 2018-Feb? or something else?

Comment: @KhalidSaifaldeen I have the numbers in a number format.  So they just appear as 201701.  No date formatting.  I took the comma that excel automatically places every three digits out.

Comment: @Jarom I mean when the inputbox appears and you want the user to input a number. You want him to input 201801 to represent Jan-2018?

Comment: @KhalidSaifaldeen Sorry for the misunderstanding.  What you said is correct.  I want the user to input YYYYMM, so something like 201801 or 201802, representing Jan-2018 and Feb-2018 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the code below (Copy Everything). The private function I added basically takes a YYYYMM format and converts it to a date format that excel understand.

```
Sub xaxis_reset()
  Dim start_yr_mnth_cd As Variant
  Dim end_yr_mnth_cd As Variant
  Dim w As Long, ws As Long
  Dim z As Long, obj As Long

  start_yr_mnth_cd = InputBox("Start YR_MNTH_CD")
  end_yr_mnth_cd = InputBox("End YR_MNTH_CD")

  start_yr_mnth_cd=ConvertYYYYMM_To_Date(start_yr_mnth_cd)
  end_yr_mnth_cd=ConvertYYYYMM_To_Date(end_yr_mnth_cd)
  ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2

  For w = 1 To ws
    obj = Worksheets(w).ChartObjects.Count
    For z = 1 To obj
      Worksheets(w).ChartObjects(z).Activate
      With ActiveChart
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = start_yr_mnth_cd
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = end_yr_mnth_cd
      End With
    Next z
  Next w
End Sub

Private Function ConvertYYYYMM_To_Date(vDate As Variant) As Date

ConvertYYYYMM_To_Date = DateValue(Right(vDate, 2) & "-" & Left(vDate, 4))

End Function
```

Hope this helps